# The process cannot access the file used by another process

Tags: c#, arrays, thread-sleep, word-automation

I have a windows application (in C#) which sends a DOC file to a pdf printer, creates pdf and read the bytes. The application uses word automation to print pdf using the following code

```
object Background = false; //to make sure the pdf file is created before continuing
wordApp.Visible = true;
wordApp.ActivePrinter = printerName;/*pdf printer*/
wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref objFileName,
 ref missing, ref objFalse, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
 ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
 ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
wordDoc.Activate();

wordDoc.PrintOut( Background, ref missing, ref Range, ref missing,
    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref Copies,
    ref missing, ref PageType, ref PrintToFile, ref Collate,
    ref missing, ref ManualDuplexPrint, ref PrintZoomColumn,
    ref PrintZoomRow, ref missing, ref missing);

do
{System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
} while (wordApp.BackgroundPrintingStatus > 0);
wordDoc.Close(ref objFalse, ref missing, ref missing);
```

After creating the pdf, i read the bytes using

```
bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Path.ChangeExtension(fileName, "pdf"));
```

Even though i set the background to false, it take a second or so for the file to be created in the directory, so readallbytes fails as it cannot find the file. I added the following code to wait for a time period so the pdf file appears

```
while (!File.Exists(Path.ChangeExtension(fileName, "pdf")))
{
 System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Path.ChangeExtension(fileName, "pdf"));
```

But sometimes i get exception that filename.pdf does not exist or i get process cannot access the file as it is being used by another process. I do not understand why file is not accessible as i am not doing anything that would lock the file and another thing i don't get it is i could read the bytes sometimes but thats does not happen always. I get not found error, does that mean the file is not created with in the sleep timeframe?

Comment: if you are using `Microsoft.Interop` I would suggest that you look up how to use `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(` method of you can try `GC.Collect(); GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()`

Comment: I am doing that in finally block which looks like `Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wordapp)`

Comment: that's good to know since  you don't actually display that..not a big deal I would suggest using a FileSystemWatcher.. and there are a few things you would need to set when using one .one in particular is turning off the listner event and turning it back on ..had the same issue 3 weeks ago and I made a simple change to turn off the event that listens until I was completely finished with the file then turned it back on..

Comment: Could you please explain? Is this to avoid firing the delegate more than once? I did the following in onCreated `watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;` in `try` block and `watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;` in finally block. Do i need to call in the main method where we call the oncreated delegate?

Comment: yes.. you can set that to = false..and when completed in a callback for example set `watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to do this with `Thread.Sleep`, I suggest you use a [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) object to monitor the folder for newly-created or newly-renamed files.  This will allow you to set up an event to trigger the code for subsequent processing when the file is ready.

Comment: Is there anyway other than using FileSystemWatcher, i do not want to have a separate thread to check the file exists because files get generated all the time and it would cause some issue if wrong files are picked and executed in the delegate. I set the background = false in the word automation which means the the code would move to the next line only after creating the file which is happening but file take a small amount of time to appear in the directory and readallbytes fail if the file is not there.

Comment: Then put some sort of signature like a GUID in the file name so that there is no chance of picking the wrong file.